# Node.js - Find port http server is listening on?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a small hello world HTTP server that listens on an unassigned port. The issue is that I am not sure how to find out which port the server is listening on. The code is as follows:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(0, '127.0.0.1', function (event) {
    // TODO register with service registry
    console.log('event: ', event);
});
```

The documentation states:

> This function is asynchronous. The last parameter callback will be
>   added as a listener for the 'listening' event. See also
>   net.Server.listen(port).

The issue is that even if my callback is called, no defined parameter is passed and I am not sure what public function or property on 'this' would provide me the value I am looking for.

Comment: See also net.Server.listen(port).

Comment: why let the http to create your server on a random port?

Comment: Because I will be creating a cluster of peer to peer, REST based, services, that will discover each other either via a UDP broadcast or mDNS. There may be multiple instance on the same host or across the network. The port is not what matters here, since it is not user facing. The user facing service will be on a fixed port and abstract this behind the scenes.

Comment: BTW curious as to the '-1'. Seems to be from someone who didn't fully understand the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading further into the documentation, it turns out I can do:

```
this.address().port
```

since Server extends net.Server